# Word for working at a certain post but not made official

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working as a Project Manager from the last few months but my official designation is still of a software engineer. The official role change will happen next year but I want to use "Project Manager" as my designation because I want recruiters see me in that position. Is there any word which can specify this?

[I saw some profiles on LinkedIn writing "Manager (Designate)" - is "designate" the word I am looking for?]

Comment: I think _designate_ is **exactly** the word you are looking for - as per [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/designate_2), "chosen for a particular job but not yet officially doing that job," it seems to me to be more fitting and more precise than any alternative I can think of - _caretaker,_ _acting_ etc.

Comment: The contradiction occurs more than once in your own narration, so of course, ("Designate") is ruled out. While the parenthetical ("Designate") does exist and is used often, that is not what you should use.

Comment: Your position can at best be called "Project Manager-in-Charge," especially if there's no other person officially designated as "Project Manager."

Comment: @tmgr That definition is **exactly** the opposite of the position in question.

Comment: @Kris: I don't understand your comments at all. I would say "Project Manager (designate)" is fine here. "Acting Project Manager" is also possible, but it suggests that the role change may only be temporary.

Comment: "designate" definitions: *Appointed but not yet installed in office. *Appointed, but not yet in office. *Appointed to an office or post but not yet installed. *Named or selected for an office, position, etc., but not yet installed. *Chosen but not yet installed

Comment: @Kris, you'll have to explain that all to me... exactly, if you can, please. I can't see how the definition I gave is the opposite of anything relevant and your comments are beyond me.

Taking a guess at what you might mean, it's worth noting one could be designated a designation (a "designation designate") and yet still have another _current_ designation - all without any contradiction. The question stands regardless of its phrasing; repetitive wording in the question has no bearing on its merits as a question or, indeed, on its answer.

Comment: @tmgr Zebrafish has provided some helpful info in the comment above. Hope that helps. Do let me know.

Comment: @Zebrafish So, according to you "designate" is the right word?

Comment: @Phoenix I've just simply listed the definitions from official dictionaries. They are all along the lines of "Appointed/named/selected/chosen for a position or office but not yet "installed/in office" Whether this applies to you, I don't know. You say you've already taken up the role but don't have the official title of Project Manager. I'm not in a position to say whether this applies to you. Someone else will have to help. If you don't get a solution here, consider the Workplace Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/118661/85135 cross-posted to the workplace

Answer (score 1):

The most common usage in American English is [Acting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acting):

> holding a temporary rank or position : performing services temporarily; *acting* president

It is frequently used in politics, when the person holding a post has left, but no one has been appointed and/or confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

The word[s] you are looking for is "interim", "pro tem", or "[pro tempore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_tempore)".  That being said,  just calling yourself a project manager is probably not a big deal. You can always clarify when asked about details.

Answer (score 0):

(BrE) **Secondment**

In many organisations in Britain, the term would be [Secondment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/secondment):

> The temporary transfer of an official or worker to another position or employment.

---

This is used for both being temporarily promoted to a higher position, and for being moved to an entirely different office/employment. It does not prohibit the role change from becoming permanent - but it implies you are expected to return to your previous role after a given time.